# svg rectangle blinking on hover

Tags: html, css, svg

can anyone explain why the svg rectangle is blinking on hover? I thought it should remain stable.  I would like an infobox on hover, but I don't want to use Jquery. The rectangle in question is the orange one to the right (Graphic designer) demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0yphnkmL/2/

css:

```
#hover
{
    width:200px; 
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    fill:white;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    left:10px;
}

#graphic_volunteer_print:hover +#hover
{
    display:block;
}
```

html:

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="1336px" height="318px" viewBox="0 0 1336 318" enable-background="new 0 0 1336 318" xml:space="preserve">
<rect id="buc" x="1" fill="#BBBBAA" width="1089" height="291"/> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="stylesvg.css"?>
<rect id="ams" x="1088" fill="#C7B299" width="248" height="291"/>
<polygon id="graphic_logo" fill="#F08F1D" stroke="#F15A24" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="1266.5,170.5 1077.5,170.5 1077.5,68.5 
    1266.5,68.5 1288.8,119.5 "/>
<rect id="languages" x="146.5" y="125.5" fill="#0095FF" stroke="#0060A1" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="102" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 127.5567 142.5293)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Technical suport in talian</text>
<rect id="tourism_guide" x="450.5" y="68.5" fill="#0071BC" stroke="#003659" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="627" height="102"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 455.9814 88.6112)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Incoming Tour Guide</text>
<rect id="graphic_pr" x="570.5" y="125.5" fill="#F7931E" stroke="#F15A24" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="73" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 575.5356 143.9356)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">PR Assistant</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.0342 38.9139)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Bucharest</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1096.8906 38.9141)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Amsterdam</text>
<rect id="graphic_teacher_volunteer" x="780" y="77" fill="#FBB03B" width="12" height="93"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 3.400014e-003 -3.400014e-003 1 791.6746 99.1751)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8783">Teacher of Graphic Design</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 794.9139 118.8516)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="17.3111">Vo</text>
<polygon id="graphic_volunteer_print" fill="#F7931E" stroke="#F15A24" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="1266.2,170.5 1139.5,170.5 
    1139.5,93.5 1266.2,93.5 1283.6,132 "/> 
<g id="hover">
    <rect fill="#fff" x="1100" y="50" fill="#FBB03B" width="300" height="200"/> 
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1143.3047 109.7091)" fill="#000" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784"> 
    DTP for music teachers' books. Software used: Word (as there are many multi-page tables that cannot automatically be transferred to InDesign) and InDesign (for the covers)
    </text>

</g>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1143.3047 109.7091)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Graphic Designer </text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 606.5869 279.8994)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Raleway-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">E d u c a t i o n</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 600.0967 23.2061)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Raleway-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">E x p e r i e n c e</text>
<polygon id="web_freelancer" fill="#C1272D" points="1266.4,170 1243,170 1243,131 1266.4,131 1276.9,150.5 "/>
<g>

        <text transform="matrix(0.9985 -5.487938e-002 5.487938e-002 0.9985 1250.528 148.2357)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Web Designer</text>
</g>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1251.6083 165.6192)" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Fr</text>
<rect id="tourism_agent" x="983.5" y="125.5" fill="#1383CF" stroke="#004D80" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="90" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 990.4646 142.5293)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Travel Agent for Europe</text>
<rect id="web_freelancer_quasar" x="948.5" y="125.5" fill="#C1272D" stroke="#470E11" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="35" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 959.7529 101.8564)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Web Designer</text>
<line id="bara" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="955" y1="90" x2="955" y2="148"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 456.9197 111.1162)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Fr</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 575.5359 164.5643)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="14.6768">Ft</text>
<rect id="languages_french" x="643.5" y="125.5" fill="#0095FF" stroke="#003D66" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="287" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 648.4424 143.9364)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Customer service in French</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 653.6263 163.1581)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Pt</text>
<rect id="academic_edu_arts" x="118" y="200" fill="#006837" width="425" height="45"/>
<rect id="academic_edu_arts_master" x="1097" y="200" fill="#006837" width="142" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 203.7442 222.2325)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Bachelor of Arts - National University of Arts    </tspan><tspan x="237" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784" letter-spacing="13">    </tspan><tspan x="253.2" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">   </tspan><tspan x="261.1" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784" letter-spacing="40"> </tspan><tspan x="303.8" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784" letter-spacing="47">    </tspan><tspan x="354.4" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">    </tspan><tspan x="365" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784" letter-spacing="37">  </tspan><tspan x="405.1" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784" letter-spacing="47">                                    </tspan><tspan x="860.8" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">        Master of Arts - Vrije University</tspan></text>
<rect id="graphic_photoshop_education" x="565" y="200" fill="#F7931E" width="69" height="45"/>
<rect id="tourism_agent_edu" x="686" y="200" fill="#0071BC" width="97" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 700.6321 217.543)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Travel Agent </tspan><tspan x="7.9" y="20.3" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">and Guide</tspan></text>
<rect id="web_edu" x="837" y="200" fill="#C1272D" width="85" height="45"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 841.6562 217.5419)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">HTML and CSS </tspan><tspan x="8.4" y="20.3" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Developper</tspan></text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 552.4734 220.3575)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Adobe Photoshop </tspan><tspan x="24.5" y="20.3" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Designer</tspan></text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 959.7537 119.5556)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Fr</text>
<polygon id="arrow_right" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="1268.2,200.5 1136.5,200.5 1136.5,169.5 
    1268.2,169.5 1283.6,185 "/>
<rect id="_x32_014" x="994.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_013" x="1136.5" y="-236.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="131" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_012" x="852.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_011" x="710.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_010" x="568.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_009" x="426.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_008" x="284.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_007" x="142.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<rect id="_x32_006" x="0.5" y="169.5" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="142" height="31"/>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 55.9614 189.1788)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">06</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 203.1777 189.1788)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">07</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 348.2436 189.1787)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">08</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 483.2709 189.1786)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">09</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 635.4096 189.1786)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">10</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 768.3261 189.1786)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">11</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 913.6699 189.1776)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">12</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 1050.5703 189.1786)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">13</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.9968 0 0 1 1196.8506 189.1788)" fill="#E6E6E6" font-family="'MyriadPro-Regular'" font-size="16.8784">14</text>
<line id="bara_oriz" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="783" y1="82" x2="818" y2="82"/>
<text transform="matrix(1.1875 0 0 1 152.4101 161.751)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Pt</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1144.0088 129.0498)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="17.3111">Leerorkest</tspan><tspan x="0" y="20.8" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="17.3111">Vo </tspan></text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 990.4637 161.7509)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Ft</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1081.8868 82.9871)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Logo Designer</tspan><tspan x="0" y="20.3" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Fr</tspan></text>
<text transform="matrix(1.1875 0 0 1 5.9209 310.8965)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Pt</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 26.2607 310.8964)" fill="#333333" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Part-time Job</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 214.6704 310.8965)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Ft</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 231.7796 310.8964)" fill="#333333" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Full-time Job</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 120.5528 310.8964)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Fr</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 137.4082 310.8964)" fill="#333333" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Freelancer</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 323.4554 310.7891)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="17.3111">Vo</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 343.7661 310.8964)" fill="#333333" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Volunteer</text>
<rect id="leg_porto" x="924.5" y="294.5" fill="#F7931E" stroke="#F15A24" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="23" height="23"/>
<g>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 954.8308 310.2246)" fill="#333333" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Graphic Design</text>
</g>
<rect id="leg_albastru" x="609.5" y="294.5" fill="#0095FF" stroke="#003D66" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="23" height="23"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 639.7676 310.3338)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Language jobs</text>
<rect id="leg_verde" x="413" y="294" fill="#006837" width="23" height="22"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 442.8544 309.6308)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Academic Education - Arts</text>
<rect id="leg_bleu" x="755.5" y="294.5" fill="#0071BC" stroke="#003659" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="23" height="23"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 786.0469 310.2256)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Tourism Language Jobs</text>
<rect id="leg_rosy" x="1060" y="294" fill="#C1272D" width="23" height="22"/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1089.8574 310.9288)" fill="#1A1A1A" font-family="'Agency Fb'" font-size="16.8784">Front end Development</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that only one tag can be hovered by the time. The infobox appear, the mouse is no longer on the orange polygon, but the hover is on infobox. So infobox disappear, because the orange polygon lose the hover, but after disappearing the orange polygon gets hover again.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried with a div on hover but it does not hover on the text contained in the polygon, not even i grouped it with the polygon. Do you know how can I make it hover over the text also?

Comment: oh, ignore my comments, the group worked.

Comment: I'm glad to hear, that it works. Can you please mark it as solved if I have answered all the questions?